# Laptop randomly freeze, and have to hard reset each time

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

My recent Gigabyte laptop randomly freeze and each time I have to hard reset it..

It happens, for now, when I'm playing on it, and the screen, keyboard, mouse, are completely blocked.

I tried to check on the Event Viewer any suspicious activities, but I can't see anything which can explain such freeze.

The laptop heat quite a lot while I'm playing, about 95°C for the CPU and less for the GPU. Besides, all my drivers are up-to-date and I'm on Windows 10.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

95°C for a laptop CPU is **very high**.

See if you can clear your CPU fan for dust that might be getting in the way of efficient airflow.

The maximum operating temperature for an Intel i7-6700HQ is 100° according to [cpu-world](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7-6700HQ%20Mobile%20processor.html)

Comment: It could also be dry/bad/not enough thermal paste to conduct heat away fast enough.

Comment: I don't think it can be the dust because I bought this laptop as new a month ago. I have a i7-6700HQ @ 2.60GHz.